# Moving site made easier

Tags: installation, customization

I have a HUGE pet peeve with Wordpress that honestly drives me crazy. Everytime you move the website, you have to go into the database in the new environment, and change in the table wp_options the "siteurl" and the "home".

This is extremely annyoing. I wish that my "moving" procedure would be as simple as:

1. Copy file tree
2. Copy database
3. Done

Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

For the specific settings you are asking about you can hardcode the values into your `wp-config.php` file(s):

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

These values will be used and database values will be ignored and not editable in settings.

Note that there are plenty more places that might store URLs, such as images in content and so on. There are solutions around that specialize in migrations and/or replacing data in WP database. Those would be more robust in this regard than making it a manual-ish process.

Comment: Well, here I have the same problem. I have to still change this variables, but not in the database but in the files. It is just a little more convenient, but not really a solution.

Comment: @Dbugger the point is that you _can_ do this in config file, _how_ can be different from manual editing. You can do it based conditionally on the domain of the request, etc.

Comment: Aha, so you mean take the domain of the request, and add it to the define? That is not a bad idea. I will think about how implementing that

Comment: Weird. changing that doesnt work on functions like bloginfo()